# VBA to remove jpg file from word doc and to delete pages using books marks

Tags: vba, ms-word, jpeg, bookmarks

Good day!

Looking at using VBA to remove a photo/jpg from a word doc using button presses via user form. Example: If I wanted to create a memo, then it keeps it. If I wanted to create another form (not memo) then removes photo. I have the photo pre-positioned using warp text formatted to the right. I've tried using the Find/Search function in word to find special graphic to replace it. >g but it could not find the jpg that I wanted to remove. It seems that Word doesnt detect that photo/jpg. see picture.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr97D.jpg)

My code that I tried;

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("memodep").Delete
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("memounit").Delete
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("memoloc").Delete
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("memoaddress").Delete

Do While ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count > 0
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete
Loop

Intro.Hide
OPORD.Show
```

or

```
Dim dod.jpg As InlineShape
For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
objPic.Delete
Next objPic
End Sub


Intro.Hide
OPORD.Show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have the photo pre-positioned using warp text formatted to the right."

This means that the logo is a `Shape` rather than an `InlineShape`.

Assuming that you only have the one, `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Delete` should do the job.

Of course, when you delete the logo all of the text to the right of it will move back to the left margin.

EDIT:
Your question left out the vital information that the logo is in the header.

Your first task is to determine which section the header is contained in. Your second is to determine which of the 3 possible headers the logo is contained in.

To point you in the right direction:

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(1).Delete
```

BTW, dod.jpg is not a valid name for a variable in VBA

Comment: It is floating using "with Text Wrapping" with the setting "In Front of Text. the file name is dod.jpg. and when I try the code you provided above, i get a run-time error of collection is out of bounds. My objective is to maintain center bookmarks where they are at. Do I have to rename the original file?

Comment: First off, I apologize for leaving the information out. I assumed with the photo you were able to tell that it is in a header status. That worked!  forgive me but why does it do that? I have hundreds of word docs that will search of anything in any position(Control F) to find anything in the footers/Headers to the body of the page.

Comment: @RoyZacharias - Find can only find text, not shapes. When working in VBA you work directly with the various elements of a document and studiously avoid selecting anything. If you open a Word document in 7-Zip it may help you to better understand its structure.

Answer (score 1):

If the graphic is inline with text, you can select it and create an extra bookmark that encloses it. Then use the same code as for the text deletions inside bookmarks.

If the graphic is floating, it is anchored to text. (**File>Options>Display>Object anchors** to make them visible) Deleting the paragraph to which the graphic is anchored will also delete the graphic.

I suspect it is floating, because your code that uses InlineShapes is not working.

Comment: Creating a new bookmark is not my objective I think. Could it be the fact its not detecting it due to it being in the header? current image properties; It is floating using "with Text Wrapping" with the setting "In Front of Text. the file name is dod.jpg.

Comment: The file name is irrelevant. Word only keeps track of file names for linked pictures, it renames embedded ones. As Timothy pointed out and I implied, InlineShapes will never find a floating shape. Depending on the actual section of your document, and also which type of header the shape is in, you may have to review Timothy's code to make the VBA work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.section.headers

Comment: I asked Timothy on this but, why is that that when I control F and able to find anything, header/footer/body but the graphic function can find a simple photo in the header?